# error using class method in views in Rails3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an Alpha that can contain several Betas. I want to filter only the Alphas that don't contain any Betas yet (hence the empty Alphas). So I created a class method in Alpha and I try to use it in the form in the view of Beta.

```
class Beta
    belongs_to :alpha
end

class Alpha
    has_many :betas

    def _empty
        return self if self.betas.nil?
    end
end

#views/betas/form.haml:

=simple_form_for @beta do |f|
    f.association :alpha, collection: Alpha._empty
```

This is the error I get:

```
undefined method '_empty' for #Class:0x0000000551ae50
```

It seems I'm missing sth basic here, I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_empty is an instance method and will return a value for the current instance, but it's not a global method that works on `Alpha`

So you may want to add a class method...

```
def self._empty
  Alpha.includes(:betas).where( :betas => { :alpha_id => nil } )
end
```

Note there are at least two ways to define a class method... with `self` in the method name...

```
 def self._empty
```

... or ...

```
class Alpha
  class << self
    def _empty
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Just defining the method unadorned makes it an instance method (e.g. `@my_alpha._empty`)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. It cleared everything out, really appreciate it.